# How to understand crash report iOS testing on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, debugging, crash

When I test my iOS app on my iPhone, it crashes immediately. From Xcode, Window->Devices->iPhone, I'm able to get the following crash report:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000100a69dc0
Termination Signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  3

Filtered syslog:
None found


Thread 3 name:  Dispatch queue: NSOperationQueue 0x170228680 :: 
NSOperation 0x17005ba80 (QOS: DEFAULT)
Thread 3 Crashed:
0   libswiftCore.dylib              0x0000000100a69dc0 0x10090c000 +     1433024
1   appName_iOS                     0x00000001000a6510 0x10000c000 +     632080
2   appName_iOS                     0x0000000100019b38 0x10000c000 +     56120
3   CFNetwork                       0x0000000192c101fc __75- [__NSURLSessionLocal taskForClass:request:uploadFile:bodyData:completion:]_block_invoke + 32
4   CFNetwork                       0x0000000192c27ef8 __49-[__NSCFLocalSessionTask _task_onqueue_didFinish]_block_invoke + 148
5   Foundation                      0x00000001930d5804 __ NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 16
6   Foundation                      0x000000019301a760 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 96
7   Foundation                      0x000000019300ab18 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 612
8   Foundation                      0x00000001930d7ba0 __NSOQSchedule_f + 228
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001914be9a0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001914ccad4 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 928
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001914c22cc _dispatch_queue_invoke + 884
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001914cea50 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 540
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001914ce7d0 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 124
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001916c71d0 pthread_wqthread + 1096
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001916c6d7c start_wqthread + 4

Thread 3 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
x0: 0x0000000100f00380   x1: 0x00000001702e5a80   x2: 0x0000000000000008   x3: 0x00000001916472c0
x4: 0x0000000000000038   x5: 0x0000000000000010   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000d60
x8: 0x00000001702e5c00   x9: 0x00000001702e5c00  x10: 0x0000000000000001  x11: 0xbaddc0dedeadbead
x12: 0x0000010000000100  x13: 0x0000000000000028  x14: 0x0000000000000001  x15: 0x0000000000000881
x16: 0x0000000191637a1c  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000174051cd0
x20: 0x0000000000000000  x21: 0x00000001a0eeac53  x22: 0x0000000000000000  x23: 0x0000000174051cd0
x24: 0x0000000000000000  x25: 0x00000000000000d8  x26: 0x00000001b737b000  x27: 0x000000016e0570e0
x28: 0x0000000000000000   fp: 0x000000016e056700   lr: 0x0000000100a69dc0
sp: 0x000000016e0566f0   pc: 0x0000000100a69dc0 cpsr: 0x20000000
```

Of course, I'm unable to understand the crash report and where the problem occurred. I know I need to symbolicate the report, can someone point me in the right direction on how to symbolicate?

Answer (score 0):

Xcode needs the symbols (dSYM) from the exact build that triggered the build on the Mac that symbolicates the crash reports. Each build is identified with a unique UUID (one for each CPU architecture) which is embedded in the app binary and the symbol file. The crash report contains that UUID in the `Binary Images` section for each loaded binary. The symbolication process uses Spotlight to find the proper symbol, and if it can't find it, is not able to symbolicate the memory address of the corresponding stack frames.

Whenever you change code in your project (or change build settings) and trigger a new build, then the UUID will change as well and the new symbol file can not be used for crash reports of older builds.

So if you don't have the symbol for that specific app build available, it is not possible to get the symbols without manual efforts.

If you didn't change the code or build settings, you could try to symbolicate the app specific frames manually via the terminal. To do that follow these steps:

1. Create a new build (make sure to use the same build configuration!).
2. Then you need the load address from the app binary from the crash report (It's the first memory address in the line below `Binary Images` which mentions your app).
3. You also need the CPU architecture of that binary image, e.g. `arm64`, or `armv7`, or `armv7s` (If the build was done for the device). In your case it looks like the build is for `arm64` as the shown data shows 64bit addresses.

Now call `atos` with the list of memory addresses you want to symbolicate (example uses the memory address of frame 1 and 2):

```
atos -arch arm64 -l TheLoadAddressOfTheBinary -o YourDsymPackage.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/YourDsymFile  0x00000001000a6510 0x0000000100019b38
```

You should now get 2 symbols for the 2 provided memory addresses. If you are lucky (when using a new dSYM), they are helpful.